# Browing java.* docs directy from Clojure Repl

Tags: java, clojure

I know about (doc ...)

I know about (user/clojuredocs ...)

I am a greedy bastard, and want to know if I can view java.*.*.* documentation from my repl [rather than googling for "java7 java.awt.Rectangle"] all the time.

Thanks!
 nx,

### EDIT:

Because I am not scrooge mcduck, and tis the festive seasons, I am also willing to accept answers that function entirely within the CLI w/o using a browser (disqualifies w3m, lynx, links) --- but a pure CLI solution that does not use the clojure repl is acceptable too.

Comment: would it be acceptable to use a browser but not leave emacs? or is that cheating?

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt: as a VIM user, I'd upvote but not accept.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can start browsing the documentation from your repl using "clojure.java.javadoc":

```
(use 'clojure.java.javadoc)
(javadoc java.awt.Rectangle)
```

It opens "default" browser (you can define w3m or any cli browser as default browser) with the javadoc.